# How to re-label Object in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Extending a previous question about JavaScript and jQuery, I'm trying to make an array and then look into it, but the array contains dimensions and I can't get it right..

```
var markers = [];
$.getJSON('GetList', "id"= + data.id,
        function(data){
           $.each(data.list, function(index, data) {
                }
                markers.push( {
                    category:data.category,
                    id:data.id,
                    location:{
                        latitude:data.location.latitude,
                        longitude:data.location.longitude
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        return markers;
}
```

The first thing that strikes me is that every item will now be called "Object", while default, I'm still wondering if they can be labeled instead?

Further down the line, I try to access the id to compare it to a selection by the user,
but it doesn't work.

```
    var selection = $(div_id).val();
    var arr = $.inArray(selection, markersArray.id);
    if( arr >= 0) {
        return search(selection, div_id);
    } else {
        throw("selection not found in selectionSearch()");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To label the objects, add a `toString` function, like this:

```
            markers.push({
                toString: function () { return this.something; },
                category:data.category,
                id:data.id,
                location:{
                    latitude:data.location.latitude,
                    longitude:data.location.longitude
                }
            });
```

To search the array, you'll need your own loop.
jQuery's `$.inArray` function searches the array for an exact match; it cannot be used to find an object with a matching property.
You can find a match yourself, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].id === selection)
        return search(selection, div_id);
}
throw("selection not found in selectionSearch()");
```

Comment: First of all - the toString example contains faults (rogue parentheses?) Second - shouldn't it be possible to just label the objects after data.id and find it with $.inArray?

Comment: Well, it works like you did it so, no arguments there. However I ran into "a is null" with it which is ... such a great error...

Answer (score 0):

The type of each item is Object, there is nothing strange about that. There is no reason to try to change that.

To filter out items from an array based on a property in the item, you use the `grep` method:

```
var arr = $.grep(markers, function(e){ return e.id === selection; });
```

To check if the array is empty, you don't compare the array to a number, you use the `length` property:

```
if (arr.length > 0) {
```